# Using D3 data().enter()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coffeescript

The following toy problem illustrates my issue. I have an array of "locations", say a treasure map. Each item in the array for example monsters or treasure could exist at multiple locations on the map. e.g.

```
locations = [
  {name:'treasure', color: 'blue', coords:[[100,100], [200,300]]},
  {name:'monsters', color: 'red', coords:[[100,150], [220,420], [50,50]]}
]
```

Now I want to plot these using D3. The bad/naive approach (that works - [see here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U99Zk/1/)), would look like this:

```
for location in locations
  for coords in location.coords
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', coords[0])
      .attr('cy', coords[1])
      .attr('r', 8)
      .style('fill', location.color)
      .datum(location)
```

However, when I modify the contents of the data, I don't want to have to run this naive code each time. It appears that using data() and enter() is the "correct" way to do it, but I can't figure out how it works with the sub-coordinates. e.g.

```
svg.selectAll('circle').data(locations).enter().append('circle')
  .attr('cx', (d) -> d.coords[0][0])
  .attr('cy', (d) -> d.coords[0][1])
  .attr('r', 8)
  .style('fill', (d) -> d.color)
```

This works great, but as you can see I am only printing the FIRST coordinate for each location, where I want to print them all. I suspect the only way to do this is to flatten my data array so there are 5 entries in total - 3 monsters and 2 treasure items.

Just wondering if there is a way to handle this better using D3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you need [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). The idea is that instead of appending a single element per data item, you append several. In code, it looks like this:

```
// append a `g` element for each data item to hold the circles
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.circle").data(locations)
   .enter().append("g").attr("class", "circle");

// now select all the circles in each group and append the new ones
groups.selectAll("circle")
   // the d in this function references a single data item in locations
   .data(function(d) { return d.coords; })
   .enter().append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; });
```

It works the same for update and exit selections.